# Can i use a 220v power strip with usb ports on 110v?

Tags: power-supply, usb, mains

My local power is 220v and i have a power strip that i bought locally.

I'm travelling to a country that uses 110v and i wish to bring the power strip there.

Is it safe to use my power strip there? I understand that usually those dumb power strips (those power strip that have no additional electronics inside, i.e no power indicator lights/no surge protector etc..) will have no issues.

What about my power strip with usb charging ports? is it safe to use on 110v?

The only infomation i had on the power strip in labeled on the back:

RATED PARAMETER: 2500W-10A(Max) 250V
USB OUTPUT: DC5V 3.4A(Auto) 17W
OUTPUT PORT: 3xAC | 6xUSB

[image: power strip back]

[image: power strip]

Comment: Because the outlets are a universal shape, my inclination would be yes. Do you have the model number of your power strip?

Comment: hi, i'm not worried about the plug connections, i have socket plug adaptors. the devices that i will be plugging in will be dual voltage too. i'm more worried on the power strip handling the voltage. like will the build in usb charging ports on the power strip be affected/damaged by 110v?

Comment: Questions about the usage of consumer electronics (particularly questions which critically depend on specifications which are not available) are not on topic here.  There are many switching power supplies with sufficiently wide input range to handle this; there are also many with too narrow a range.  **It is impossible to know which you have** and even matching the plastic to some other product does not mean the internals will be the same.  Realistically, this is a bulky item to pack.  Get a USB supply or two with credible rating for the destination voltage, and buy a power strip there.

Answer (score 1):

Through the powers of searching the web, multiple sellers of this device list it as having a rated voltage of 100-250 VAC. The websites also show what is stamped on the boiler plate in your picture as being the max rated power. Here is a [link](https://www.dzduino.com/multiprise-ldnio-original-3-prises-de-courant-6-port-usb) to one of the many sellers I found for this device although there does not seem to be a manufacturer's website and no datasheet.

All that to say, it'll probably work but you only have marketing to go on for that.